# tf.cast equivalent in pytorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I am new to PyTorch. TensorFlow has an API *tf.cast()* and *tf.shape()*. the *tf.cast* has specific purpose in TensorFlow, is there anything equivalent in torch? 
i have tensor x= tensor(shape(128,64,32,32)): *tf.shape(x)* create tensor of dimension 1 *x.shape* create the true dimension. i need to use *tf.shape(x)* in torch.

*tf.cast* has a different role than just changing tensor *dtype* in torch.

did anyone have equivalent API in torch/PyTorch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out the [PyTorch Documentation](https://johnwlambert.github.io/pytorch-tutorial/#data-types)

As they mentioned:

```py
print(x.dtype) # Prints "torch.int64", currently 64-bit integer type
x = x.type(torch.FloatTensor)
print(x.dtype) # Prints "torch.float32", now 32-bit float
print(x.float()) # Still "torch.float32"
print(x.type(torch.DoubleTensor)) # Prints "tensor([0., 1., 2., 3.], dtype=torch.float64)"
print(x.type(torch.LongTensor)) # Cast back to int-64, prints "tensor([0, 1, 2, 3])"
```