# tf.bitcast equivalent in pytorch?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch

This question is different from [tf.cast equivalent in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59132647/tf-cast-equivalent-in-pytorch).

bitcast do bitwise reinterpretation(like `reinterpret_cast` in C++) instead of "safe" type conversion.

This operation is useful when you want to store bfloat16 tensor with numpy.

```py
x = torch.ones(224, 224, 3, dtype=torch.bfloat16
x_np = bitcast(x, torch.uint8).numpy()
```

Currently numpy doesn't natively support bfloat16, so `x.numpy()` will raise `TypeError: Got unsupported ScalarType BFloat16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 2nd overload [torch.Tensor.view](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html).

Its semantic is closely similar to [numpy.ndarray.view](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html).